# 301 Redirect - preg match rule in .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want to achieve that all links which have the following structure

```
http://www.example.com/hair-removal/
http://www.example.com/hair-removal/sub
http://www.example.com/hair-removal/sub/supersub
```

are redirected to

```
http://www.example.com/hair-removal-new/
http://www.example.com/hair-removal-new/sub
http://www.example.com/hair-removal-new/sub/supersub
```

How can I achieve this with an htaccess file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want it for `/hair-removal/*` and leave other URL unchanged, use this:

```
RewriteRule ^hair-removal/(.*)$ /hair-removal-new/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/ $1-new/ [R=301,NC,L]
```